# Creating charts using d3.js and canvas together

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, charts, html5-canvas

I have been using [D3.js](https://d3js.org/) library to create some basic graphs. I'm trying to create a bar graph with HTML5 canvas but finding it hard to create.I found some resources and [this](https://blockbuilder.org/ashtonburg/2d788f6fbeced724ea6e) chart but I'm unable to understand how it's done.Can you guys suggest some resources/tutorials/books/blogs of D3.js with canvas so I can have a better idea how it's done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My first thoughts reading this are that there may be a bit of a mismatch. There's no reason you shouldn't be able to use D3.js and canvas together, but I think you'll find it much easier working with SVG instead of canvas with D3, plus you get all sorts of benefits in terms of animation, CSS manipulation, and accessiblity.

If you do want to stick to canvas then use [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) instead of D3, it's designed to work with canvas and presents a much more gentle learning curve, being a more out-of-the-box solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gavin